# When a load balancer terminates an SSL connection does it create a new TCP connection to the destination server?

Tags: ssl, web, load-balancing

A layer 3 Nat load balancer simply overwrites the ip addresses in the layer 3 headers and forwards the packet on.  All of the TCP stuff stays the same.

What happens in a SSL terminating load balancer?  I'm thinking it's the server that the client forms the syn/ack TCP connection with and then the LB recieves the SSL packet unwraps/dencrypts it then creates a new TCP connection with the back end and forwards this packet on?

Am I conceptualizing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SSL terminating load balancer terminates (as the name says) the SSL connection, i.e. forwards either the decrypted traffic to the final target or a newly encrypted traffic. Since the payload is different (which also means payload size might differ) this can only be done with a new TCP connection.